# how can i get the result in sparql query of the following?

Tags: sparql

2.5) List the people and their names who are born in Jönköping before 1900.
2.6) Are there musical artists who were born in Jönköping? (use an ASK query).
2.7) Find 10 people (URI and place of death) who were born in Jönköping, but died elsewhere.

I am using dbpedia to run queries and fetch data
SELECT DISTINCT * WHERE {?x ?y "Jönköping"@en }

This is the URI Which is retrived
DESCRIBE [http://dbpedia.org/resource/Jönköping](http://dbpedia.org/resource/J%C3%B6nk%C3%B6ping)

Comment: "Solve my homework" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Instead, you should provide a honest attempt to solve the problems. Then, seek for answers where you are completely stuck. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: SELECT ?person ?name WHERE {
?person <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthPlace> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Jönköping> .
?person <http://dbpedia.org/property/name> ?name.
}

Comment: I have tried this query but it shows all the result. I only want to select those who where born before 1900

Comment: you have to apply a [`FILTER`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#termConstraint) on the date which indeed you also have to select via another triple pattern

Comment: SELECT ?person ?name WHERE {
?person <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthPlace> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Jönköping> .
?person <http://dbpedia.org/property/name> ?name.
?person <http://dbpedia.org/property/date> ?date.
}

Comment: I tried this. It gives 5 result Only WHERE can i apply FILTER as I have no idea. I am beginner. :(

Answer (score 1):

You can solve as following;

> 2.5) List the people and their names who are born in Jönköping before 1900

```
PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> 
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
    
SELECT ?name ?birth
    WHERE
    {      
      ?person dbo:birthPlace db:Jönköping . 
      ?person dbo:birthDate ?birth .   
      ?person foaf:name ?name .      
      FILTER (?birth < "1900-01-01"^^xsd:date) . 
    } 
ORDER BY ?birth
```

> 2.6) Are there musical artists who were born in Jönköping? (use an ASK query)

```
PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> 
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 

ASK WHERE{SELECT ?person WHERE{      
 ?person a dbo:MusicalArtist .
 ?person dbo:birthPlace db:Jönköping .       
}}
```

> 2.7)Find 10 people (URI and place of death) who were born in Jönköping, but died elsewhere

```
PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> 
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 

SELECT DISTINCT ?name ?person
WHERE
{      
  ?person dbo:birthPlace db:Jönköping . 
  ?person dbo:deathPlace ?deathPlace. 
  ?person foaf:name ?name . 
  FILTER (?deathPlace != db:Jönköping) .  
} ORDER BY ?name LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Ah! Thank You Very Much :)

Comment: 1) solving their university assignments is not useful ... 2) there is no need to nest a `SELECT` query inside the `ASK` query in exercise 2.6, you can just use the graph pattern of the `SELECT` query

Comment: Thanks for the comment UninformedUser, I have also mentioned your first point under the question comments. Yet, I cannot let go a honest attempt to solve the question and request for a decent solution. Can you elaborate on your second point? How can we improve with using "ASK" query as mentioned?